# google map cameraPostion

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In Google IO 2013 I heard about `SensorManager` that google map can animate when sensor is changed.

So I look their code and couldn't understand one thing -

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().
           tilt(clamp(0,mTilt,67.5)).
           bearing(mAzimuth).
           zoom((13 + 5 * (mTilt/90))).
           target(sydney).
           build();
```

What is `clamp()`? what it is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that clamp is math function, it's clamping specified value into range, in this case ensures that mTilt will have value between 0 and 67.5.

Comment: I didn't find any clamp function in Math class,

Comment: Because there isn't any. It's custom I think (btw. in my opinion easy to implement). You can find function like that in render script. Check http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.Builder.html#tilt(float) You will know why they are clamping value to 67.5